# Error while updating the database with multiple php files

Tags: php, mysql, forms

am trying to update the databse with the pubupdate.php file with the mentioned file but it is giving error Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\form.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\form.php on line 4. I don't know how this page is directed to form.php. However form.php has been used to create the account of the user so that user can login into the website. The login is done by the page login.php which is using the data which has been inserted in create.php. I don't know how to solve this problem and howcome pubupdate.php is directing to form.php and how to solve this problem.

I am posting the codes which I have used.

***pubupdate.php***

```
 <?php

$typereg = $_POST['papertype'];
$ptitlereg = $_POST['ptitle'];
$fauthorreg = $_POST['firstauthor'];
$coauthorreg = $_POST['coauthor'];
$abstractreg = $_POST['abstract'];
$nameconreg = $_POST['namecon'];
$areareg = $_POST['area'];
$datereg = $_POST['date'];
$startpagereg = $_POST['startpage'];
$endpagereg = $_POST['endpage'];
$countryreg = $_POST['country'];


$taken = "false";
$database = "publication";
$password = "";
$username = "root";


$con = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect database");
 @mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Unable to connect");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `paper` VALUES('$typereg', '$ptitlereg','$fauthorreg','$coauthorreg','$abstractreg' ,'$nameconreg', '$areareg','$datereg', '$startpagereg', '$endpagereg', '$countryreg' )") or die("Strange Error");

echo "Account Created";

 mysql_close($con);

 header('Location: home.php');

 ?>
```

***form.php***

```
<?php

$userreg = $_POST['user'];
$passreg = $_POST['pass'];



$taken = "false";
$database = "publication";
$password = "";
$username = "root";


if($userreg && $passreg){



 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die("Unalbe to  connect database");
 @mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Unalbe to connect");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('', '$userreg', '$passreg')") or die("Strange Error");

 echo "Account Created";

 mysql_close($con);

  header("Location : index.html");

 } else {

 echo "You need to have both a username and password";
 }


 ?>
```

***create.php***

```
<?php

 $userreg = $_POST['user'];
$passreg = $_POST['pass'];
$fnamereg = $_POST['fname'];
$lnamereg = $_POST['lname'];
$desigreg = $_POST['designation'];




 $taken = "false";
 $database = "publication";
 $password = "";
 $username = "root";


 if($userreg && $passreg){



 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect database");
 @mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Unable to connect");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('', '$userreg','$passreg','$fnamereg','$lnamereg' ,'$desigreg')") or die("Strange Error");

 echo "Account Created";

  mysql_close($con);

  header('Location: index.html');

  } else {

  echo "You need to have both a username and password";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: We don't need all the code only relevant code that deals with your problem.

Comment: *with the pubupdate.php file with the mentioned file but it is giving error Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Publication\form.php on line 3* clearly says the about the error and the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form where you use to get the inputs  i.e., Username and Password.

You should give it a name

**Something like**

```
<input type='text' name='user'>
<input type='password' name='pass'>
```

It is clear that you didn't give the `name` field in your code.

**Note :**

In addition you can have your class or id according to your need.

**Additional Note :**

For Debugging, I would recommend you to deal such errors easily by checking whether the value exists..

You can do it easily by the below code

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) 
{
echo 'Username value is - '.$_POST['user'];
}
```

Comment: I actually figured out the error. There was some mistake in the php code where I mistakenly mentioned home.php which has no relation with this project.